# Django: check cookies are enabled?

Tags: django, cookies, session-cookies

I want to check whether cookies are enabled in Django. I have the following code:

```
def test_cookies(request):
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
        print 'cookie worked'
        request.session.delete_test_cookie()
    else:
        print 'cookie failed'
        return HttpResponse("Please enable cookies and try again.")
```

However, if I check 'Disable Cookies > All Cookies' in Firefox's Web Developer Toolbar, and then try loading the page in Firefox, I get 'cookie worked' in the output. Oh dear.

Is there another way to check whether cookies are enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In one action/url you set a cookie and redirect it to other action/url. In that other action you check if cookie is set.

Comment: Thanks, why do I need to redirect?

Comment: ... if all I want to do is check the browser can accept cookies? Surely there must be a simpler way?

Comment: OK, this is why... Sheesh. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/http/sessions/#setting-test-cookies

Comment: Updated link for previous comment:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#setting-test-cookies